# Geometric and radiometric distribution of light

Tags: visible-light, radiometry

I'm studying the behavior of the light in a scene, to know how much light arrives at a specific point of a surface and how much of it leaves from the point.
From the documentation I'm reading, it says that this study involves both the geometric and radiometric distribution of light, but I don't know much about these two kind of distribution, especially the radiometric one: I know what geometric distribution in math is, but I don't know in which way it can be referred to the light.
What do they involve in the study of light behavior? Which different aspects do they study about the light?

Comment: This seems more of a cgi than a physics question, but then I know a physicist who wrote his habilitation paper about the subject... My best guess is that by "geometric" distribution of light they mean only the first ray from the light sources hitting the scene without any simulation of reflected light. Radiometric codes, on the other hand, are usually trying to approximate the entire light field, i.e. the direct geometric contribution plus first, second etc. orders of reflected light.

Comment: Ok, so it's like with geometric distribution I trace the first ray and then the "rays' tree" that I can construct following the secondary rays it's the radiometric contribution? By secondary rays I mean the scattered ones and the reflected ones when the primary ray hits the surface of an object

Comment: Sounds about right. I have only the vaguest recollection about the details but the problem with ray tracing for the case of diffuse reflection is that it has to follow awfully fast exploding (e.g. $16^n$!) trees of reflected rays, whereas radiometric codes ("radiosity" methods) seem to have a more efficient way of calculating the "average diffuse" light field once and then they have a fairly small penalty for lighting the individual scene surface element. That's all I really "know" about it... I haven't looked at any of this in decades and even then I only did it for fun.